# checkbox not showing in chrome and android

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, checkbox

I have a simple checkbox that is showing on FF but not in chrome or android or iphone browser.

```html
<label for="isCommentAnonymous" class="control-label com-vp-chk"><input type="checkbox" id="isCommentAnonymous" class="checkbox-inline com-vp-lbl" /> Post anonymously</label>
```

NOt sure what is wrong i looked for few tutorian tried few option but i cant see check box.

TRied

```
input[type=checkbox]
{
/*-webkit-appearance: none;*/
  -webkit-appearance:checkbox;
}
```

Comment: need further details, the error is probably not from here. Tested the code provided on chrome and it works fine

Comment: I ended up using following css `
input[type="checkbox"]:checked{background:blue; color:white}​`